# Can't set values for ArrayList of ArrayList in java

Tags: java

This is my code

```
public Solution(int n, int p) {
        this.n = n;
        this.p = p;
        graph = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0 ;i < n;i++) {
            graph.set(i, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        System.out.println(solve());
    }


public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph;
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

The value of n and p are 5, 5

Comment: Use [`graph.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) to add elements to a list, not [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)). You can't `set` indexes past the list's current size.

Comment: we don't know what "set" and"solve" are doing, and the full stackTrace would help

Comment: Why don't you simply do `graph.add(new ArrayList<>());`?

Comment: Use add instead of set

Comment: also graph is an arraylist and not a map. so use graph.add(new Arraylist<>()) as each index can hold only a single object.